# Proof of Chinese remainder theorem by isomorphism

Tags: group-theory, gcd-and-lcm, group-isomorphism, isometry, chinese-remainder-theorem

My note states that we can prove Chinese remainder theorem as the way shown: Let $m$ and $n$ be coprime natural numbers. Then $C_{mn}$ is isomorphic to $C_m \times C_n$ (where $C_m$ is cyclic group with order $m$)

I understand how to prove they are isomorphic, but I don’t understand how that prove the Chinese remainder theorem.

For example,let $m=5,n=7$. The isomorphism shows that there is a bijective map between adding the result we get after applying $\pmod {35}$ and adding $(a,b)$, where $a$ is the result after
$\pmod 5$ and $b$ is the result after $\pmod 7$. But how does it show that we could know what is $a\pmod {35}$ if we know $(a\pmod 7,a\pmod 5)$ for positive integer $a$?

---

**Edit**: I know the chinese remainder theorem as

> If one knows the remainders of the Euclidean division of an integer n by several integers, then one can determine uniquely the remainder of the division of n by the product of these integers, under the condition that the divisors are pairwise coprime (no two divisors share a common factor other than 1)

Answer (score 2):

> Let $m$ and $n$ be coprime natural numbers. Then $C_{mn}$ is isomorphic to $C_m×C_n$ (where $C_m$ is cyclic group with order $m$)

Note how the chinese remainder theorem is just a generalization of that: Let $\{n_i\}$ be pairwise coprime. Then $C_N$ is isomorphic to $C_{n_1}\times\dots\times C_{n_k}$ via the map $[x]_N\mapsto ([x_{n_1}],\dots,[x_{n_k}])$, where $N=\prod n_i$.

So maybe try to generalize your proof for only two coprime numbers to work for $k$-many pairwise coprime numbers.

---

**Edit:** OPs version of the CRT is

> If one knows the remainders of the Euclidean division of an integer $n$ by several integers, then one can determine uniquely the remainder of the division of $n$ by the product of these integers, under the condition that the divisors are pairwise coprime (no two divisors share a common factor other than 1)

Here is how you see that this is implied by the version of the CRT above:

Let $n\in \mathbb N$ be some integer and let $q_1,\dots, q_k$ be pairwise coprime integers. Suppose I know the remainders ($n$ mod $q_i$) for every $i$. All these remainders together give an element in $C_{q_1}\times\dots\times C_{q_k}$. Now using the CRT (as stated by me above) we get one element in $C_Q$ by the isomorphism, where $Q=q_1\cdot \dots\cdot q_k$. This element is precisely the remainder ($n$ mod $Q$)

Comment: Thanks but what I don’t understand is exactly your first paragraph. Why is Chinese remainder theorem a generalization of what you stated?

Comment: Do you mean why what I have written is the chinese remainder theorem? Maybe you have seen it in another form. Because once you belive that this is the CRT, then it generalizes your version with two coprime numbers to $k$ coprime numbers

Comment: Yeah I see it in another form in wikipedia and it states that “if one knows the remainders of the Euclidean division of an integer n by several integers, then one can determine uniquely the remainder of the division of n by the product of these integers, under the condition that the divisors are pairwise coprime (no two divisors share a common factor other than 1)” . And I don’t understand how the isomorphism shows this statement.

Comment: Ah I see so your question is really why these two versions of the CRT are equivalent. Let me add an explanation to the answer

Comment: Why is the one we get from isomorphism is precisely the remainder?

Comment: That is exactly how you define this isomorphism. Let me add that to the CRT above. That brings up the next question: Why is that map an isomorphism? To answer that you can mimic the proof for the version with only two corpime numbers

Comment: What does it mean by define this isomorphism? Aren’t we just showing that the 2 cyclic groups are isomorphic?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144406/discussion-between-alex-and-ppgull).

Answer (score 1):

The thing to note is not just that there is a group isomorphism $f : C_{nm} \to C_n \times C_m$.

We have canonical group homomorphisms $g : \mathbb{Z} \to C_{nm}$ and $h : \mathbb{Z} \to C_n \times C_m$. You denote these maps by $g(a) = (a \mod nm)$ and $h(a) = ((a \mod n), (a \mod m))$ (though this is not standard notation). The key here is that $f \circ g = h$. In other words, if we know $a \mod nm$ - that is, if we know $g(a)$ - we can apply $f$ to compute $h(a)$ - that is, to compute $(a \mod n, a \mod m)$. Because $f$ is an isomorphism, we can also go the other way - we have $f^{-1} \circ h = f^{-1} \circ f \circ g = g$. Thus, if we know $(a \mod n, a \mod m)$, we can apply $f^{-1}$ to compute $a \mod nm$.

Comment: Thanks I think it makes my question very clear! Could you explain some more about why applying f to g(a) would take us to the ‘right’ h(a)? This step is not obvious for me.

Comment: $a=nm\mathbb{Z}+r$ where $r$ is the remainder in $C_{nm}$, so $a=r \mod m$ and $a=r\bmod n$. What confuses me more is how we know it is an isomorphism (in particular it has an inverse)?

Comment: To my last statement: Starting with an arbitrary element $km+r \in C_{nm}$ where $k\in\{0,1,...,n-1\}$ and $r\in\{0,1,...,m-1\}$. $f$ maps $km+r$ to $(km+r \mod n , r)$. Now the map $k\mapsto km+r \mod n$ is a bijective map, since $m$ and $n$ are coprime. Hence, for every $r$ - of which there are $m$ - there are $n$ distinct tuples, so in total $m\times n$ distinct tuples corresponding to the $n\times m$ elements in $C_{nm}$.